# View Level Number on Recursive Table SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following table:

```
--------------------------------------------
ID      ParentID     Item  
--------------------------------------------
1                    root
2       1            AA
3       1            BB
4       1            CC
5       1            DD
6       2            A1
7       6            A11
ff.
```

I want to have the following result:

```
ID      ParentID     Item         Level
---------------------------------------------
1                    root         0
2       1            AA           1
3       1            BB           1
4       1            CC           1
5       1            DD           1
6       2            A1           2
7       6            A11          3
ff.
```

1. What is the best idea to create the new column `level`? Is create a new column and add a formula or something like computed or maybe function?
2. How can I achieve that on `t-sql`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select t.id, t.parentid, t.item, 0 as lvl
      from t
      where parentid is null
      union all
      select t.id, t.parentid, t.item, cte.lvl + 1 as lvl
      from t join
           cte
           on t.parentid = cte.id
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Storing this data in the table is . . . cumbersome, because you need to keep it updated.  You might want to just calculate it on-the-fly when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using `DENSE_RANK`:

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE(ID INT,ParentID VARCHAR(10),Item VARCHAR(10))
INSERT into @YourTable VALUES(1,' ','root')
INSERT into @YourTable VALUES(2,'1','AA')
INSERT into @YourTable VALUES(3,'1','BB')
INSERT into @YourTable VALUES(4,'1','CC')
INSERT into @YourTable VALUES(5,'1','DD')
INSERT into @YourTable VALUES(6,'2','A1')
INSERT into @YourTable VALUES(7,'6','A11')


SELECT ID,ParentID,Item
    ,(DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ISNULL(NULLIF(ParentID,''),0)))-1 [Level]
FROM @YourTable
```

**Output:**

```
ID  ParentID    Item    Level
1               root    0
2   1           AA      1
3   1           BB      1
4   1           CC      1
5   1           DD      1
6   2           A1      2
7   6           A11     3
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Try adding two rows , (8,' ','A12'), (9,'8','A12').  Why would anyone use different types id and parent?